# How do I download a GeoDataFrame to my local drive from Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gis, geospatial, shapefile

I am fairly new to SHAPEFiles and GeoDataFrames so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I am using Google Colab in Google Chrome on a Mac. Python version 3.xx

I have an existing Esri SHAPEFile that has CRS points (latitiude-longitude) of Polygons and MultiPolygons.

My objective was to find the centroid of these Polygons and MultiPolygons and add the centroids as a new column in the existing SHAPEfile and then save the file locally.

How do I save the file locally? What format do I use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")

df["geometry"] = df["geometry"].centroid  # assuming a projection CRS is used

df.to_file("centroids.shp", driver="Shapefile")
```

You'll need to refresh your working directory in Google Colabs to see the shapefile. Make sure you download all associated files as well.

**Note:** You cannot store more than one geometry in a shapefile.

The script creates a new shapefile using the centroids for the geometries but also keeping all other columns. That way you will be able to relate both datasets.

---

**Here is a possible workflow:**

1. Create a new Jupyter notebook or open an existing one
2. Create a **zip file** containing your shape file **including** all associated files
3. Upload it to your Colabs working directory

   - I call the file `polygons.zip` in my example
4. Run following code in a cell:

```py
!pip install geopandas

import os
import tempfile
import zipfile
import glob

import geopandas as gpd

OUTPUT_SHAPE_FILE = "centroids.shp"
SHAPE_FILE_ZIP = "polygons.zip"

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as wd:

    with zipfile.ZipFile(SHAPE_FILE_ZIP, "r") as shape_file_zip:
        shape_file_zip.extractall(wd)

    shape_file = os.path.join(wd, SHAPE_FILE_ZIP.replace(".zip", ".shp"))

    df = gpd.read_file(shape_file)

    df["geometry"] = df["geometry"].centroid  # assuming a projection CRS is used

    df.to_file(os.path.join(wd, OUTPUT_SHAPE_FILE), driver="Shapefile")

    shape_file_name = OUTPUT_SHAPE_FILE.replace(".shp", "")

    with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{shape_file_name}.zip", "w") as output_file:

        for file in glob.iglob(f"{os.path.join(wd, shape_file_name)}.*"):
            output_file.write(file, os.path.basename(file))
```

5. Refresh your working directory on Google Colabs, you'll see `centroids.zip`
6. Download the file (click on the three dots when hovering over the file)

---

**PS.** I would recommend to use a local Jupyter notebook and Python environment for such situations.